# Сложение словарей Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, перегрузка-операторов

Цель написать класс для сложения словарей.
Класс наследуется от dict, и перегружается метод  `__add__`

```
a = NewDict()

b = NewDict()

a = {'a': 1}

b = {'b': 2}

a+b
```

Результат `{'a': 1, 'b': 2}`

Подскажите как реализовать

Comment: С чем конкретно возникли сложности?

Comment: Не могу понять как перегрузить `__add__`, ошибка нельзя использовать '+' для словарей. Интересно сделать именно через перегрузку `__add__`

Answer (score 4):

Определить операцию **+** для словаря можно вот так. Магический метод `__add__` помимо self принимает ещё один аргумент other. В нашем случае оба операнда будут словарями, а в теле метода к ним обоим применяется оператор распаковки ******, чтобы получить новый словарь с объединением исходных. Такое использование двойной звёздочки допустимо, начиная только с Python 3.5 (см. [PEP-448](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/)).

```
class SummableDict(dict):
    def __add__(self, other):
        return SummableDict(**self, **other)
    def __repr__(self):
        return "SummableDict({})".format(super().__repr__())
```

Использование:

```
a1 = SummableDict({"q": 12})
a2 = SummableDict({"w": 42})
a1 + a2
```

> `SummableDict({'q': 12, 'w': 42})`

Comment: Еще неплохо было бы в ответе хотя бы вкратце рассказать как работает вот эта магия: `SummableDict(**self, **other)`

Comment: @insolor, дополнил разъяснение ссылкой на PEP